# If $A$ is an open set, then $A \subset S \leftrightarrow A \subset Int(S)$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ is an open set, then $A \subset S \leftrightarrow A \subset Int(S)$.

So in words if $A$ is an open set, then $A$ is a subset of $S$ if and only if $A$ is a subset of $int(S)$.

We know $A$ is open, so $A=Int(A)$={$a \in  A$| $a$ interior point$A$}, and $B(a, \delta) \subset A$.

I have no idea where to even start with this problem, some tips are appreciated!

Comment: You tagged your post as ([tag:real-analysis]). Are you dealing only with subsets of real line? Or with subsets of any metric spaces? Any topological space? You should probably include also what is your definition of open set and of interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathrm{int}(S) \subseteq S$, the backwards implication is trivial. Conversely, suppose $A\subseteq S$ and that $A$ is open. Let $x\in A$. Since $A$ is open, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B(x, \delta)\subseteq A$. $A\subseteq S$, and so $B(x,\delta)\subseteq S$, and so $x\in \mathrm{int}(S)$. This works for any $x\in A$, and so $A\subseteq \mathrm{int}(S)$.